# What is android opengl equivalent to surfaceHolder.lockCanvas()

Tags: android, multithreading, opengl-es

I am trying to build a game framework for a 3D android game. I was trying to do it using this tutorial,

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/android-game-development-game-loop.html

and I was able to get a 2D game framework working. The tutorial then goes on to use the OpenGL features of android, but doesn't use it in a game framework.

My question is, since I am using a separate thread to call my update and draw method, is their an equivalent to what I am doing to the canvas with the android OpenGl GL10 class?

```
try
{
    canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
    synchronized (surfaceHolder)
    {
         //Update and draw code here
    }
}
finally
{
    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
}
```

Although this should be the only object in my program using the opengl GL10 class, I want to make sure that I have control over the GL10 camera and if this is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the Canvas API and the surface holder stuff. However, using OpenGL on Android, the [`GLSurfaceView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html) seems to be what you want ([code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.java#GLSurfaceView.EglHelper.swap%28%29)). It derives from SurfaceView and uses `EGL` for low-level surface management. It already starts a second thread for rendering, calling into the [`Renderer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.Renderer.html) methods. You may want to look into the [threading model of Replica Island](http://replicaisland.blogspot.de/2009/10/rendering-with-two-threads.html); Chris uses a third thread for updating the game world.